# How to get process id of calling process if elevated via sudo

Tags: bash

I have a service on Ubuntu which elevate new process using sudo command and then call bash script XY.

**From this bash script XY I need to find process id** of the service which called the process.

Parent process id ($$) does not work, probably because sudo elevation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

ps -ef | awk '$2 == "'$PPID'" { print $3 }'
```

Run it with :

```
$ chmod +x test.sh
$ sudo ./test.sh
$ echo "Sudo should print $$."
```